# In Huffman coding, how do I choose the frequency to get the maximum average bit length?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, information-theory, coding-theory, trees

First I want to give you a little summary about the Huffmann code to avoid misunderstandings.

**Summary begins**

So we have an alphabet $A$ with $|A| > 1 $. For example $A$= {$a,b,c,d,e$}. Now we number the letters: $a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5$.

Every letter has a frequency. So we have a map $f : A \rightarrow [0,1]$ with $\sum_{a \in A} f(a) = 1$. For example $(1|0,2), (2|0,3), (3,|0,1), (4|0,35), (5|0,05)$. Let me explain my notation: $(1|0,2)$ means that the letter $a$ has frequency $0,2$.

So the Huffman code tells us that we take the two letters with the lowest frequency and combine them. So we get $(1|0,2), (2|0,3), (3,|0,15), (4|0,35)$. We get :[image]

If we repeat this process we will get:

[image]

So we can compute ABL (Average Bit Length ):

$$ ABL(\gamma) = \sum_{a \in A} f(a) \cdot |\gamma(a)| $$

where $\gamma$ is the length of the codeword. For example $\gamma(e) = 4$ like you can see in my second picture.

Any questions?

**Summary ends**

So I want to get the maximum average bit length. How do I have to choose $f$ for an alphabet $A$ with $|A| > 1$ ? I tried many things like taking the uniform distribution $f(a) = \frac{1}{n}$ for all $a \in A$ with $|A| = n$. But this and other of my ideas didn't work. Can you help me out? **Update:** : thanks to the comments I've got I find out that I made a mistake about the uniform distribution. So it could be that the uniform distriution could be the solution.

Comment: It's really not necessary that you explain the Huffman code construction, that's very well known (a link to Wikipedia suffices), there's no risk of  misunderstandings. 

Why do you say that the uniform distribution didn't work? Have you found some case where another distribution gives bigger code lenght?

Comment: You are not asking (it seems) about "the worst case" relative to the Shannon entropy - for this, see here https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4935/why-does-the-fibonacci-sequence-produce-a-worst-case-huffman-encoding/14667#14667

Comment: When $n$ is a power of 2, the uniform distribution is the worst: every distribution has a code with average codeword length $\log_2 n$, and in contrast, the entropy of the uniform distribution (which lower bounds the average codeword length) is $\log_2 n$.

Comment: For $n=3$ there is a single code, $0,10,11$. To maximize the average codeword length, we need to minimize the probability of $0$; but by construction, this needs to be the most probable symbol, hence needs to have probability at least $1/3$. We deduce that the uniform distribution is the worst for $n = 3$.

Comment: Of course an explanation of the Hufmann code is not neccessary, but  sometimes people need definitions, example etc. Oh my counterexample is not a counterexample! I made a mistake. So could it be that the uniform distribution gives us the maximum ABL? How can prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: @leonbloy: I thought it was an excellent exposition of Huffman encoding, which enhanced the question immensely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum is attained on the uniform distribution.

We need the following lemma:

> **Lemma**. Let $p_1, \ldots, p_n \in [0, 1]$ and $l_1, \ldots, l_n\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $p_1 + \ldots + p_n = 1, p_1 \ge p_2 \ge \ldots \ge p_n$ and $l_1 \le l_2 \le \ldots \le l_n$. Then
> $$ \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n p_i l_i \le \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{n} \cdot l_i.$$

**Proof.** Denote $S_{n + 1} = 0$ and  $S_i = p_{i} + \ldots + p_n$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$. Let us show that $S_i \le \frac{n - i + 1}{n}$. Indeed, otherwise there exists $j\in\{i, i + 1, \ldots, n\}$ such that $p_j > \frac{1}{n}$. This implies that $p_1 \ge p_2 \ge \ldots \ge p_{i - 1} \ge p_j > \frac{1}{n}$, hence $p_1 + \ldots + p_n = 1 \ge (i - 1) \cdot \frac{1}{n} + S_i > (i - 1) \frac{1}{n} + \frac{n - i + 1}{n} = 1$, contradiction.

Using this bound on $S_i$ we obtain:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n p_i l_i &= \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n (S_i - S_{i + 1}) l_i = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n S_i l_i  - \sum\limits_{i = 2}^{n + 1} S_i \cdot l_{i - 1} =  \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n S_i l_i  - \sum\limits_{i = 2}^{n} S_i \cdot l_{i - 1}\\
&= l_1 S_1 + (l_2 - l_1) S_2 + \ldots + (l_n - l_{n - 1}) S_n \\
&\le l_1 \frac{n}{n} + (l_2 - l_1) \frac{n - 1}{n} + \ldots  + (l_n - l_{n - 1}) \cdot \frac{1}{n} \\
&= l_1 \left(\frac{n}{n} - \frac{n - 1}{n}\right) + l_2\left(\frac{n - 1}{n} - \frac{n - 2}{n}\right) + \ldots + l_n \cdot \frac{1}{n} \\
&= \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{n} \cdot l_i. 
\end{align*}
**Lemma is proved.**

Now, suppose that the size of an alphabet is $n$.

Let $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ be codewords of the Huffman code for the uniform distribution. Further, let $l_i$ be the length of $c_i$ and assume that $l_1 \le l_2 \le \ldots \le l_n$. Take any probability distribution $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ and assume that $p_1 \ge p_2 \ge \ldots \ge p_n$.

We can use $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ as a prefix code for frequencies $p_1, \ldots, p_n$. Hence the average length of the Huffman code for $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ is at most $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n p_i l_i$. By Lemma the last quantity is at most $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{n} \cdot l_i$ and the latter is the average length of the Huffman code for the uniform distribution.

Comment: +1 But I'd bet there should be simpler proofs of the lemma. Eg, by using [Newton series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Newton_series) for $\sum l_i ( 1/n - p_i)$...